# Which rotation matrix for which axis up?

Tags: matrices, 3d, rotations

I am learning how to write 3d transformation matrices for use in Unity.
I found what I needed about translations and scaling, but when it comes to rotations, I've found two opposite examples.

I assume one is made to work in a Y-Up environnement, and the other in Z-Up, but which one is which ?

One says a XYZ rotation uses these matrices :

$$ 
    \left[ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & cos(X) & -sin(X) & 0 \\
    0 & sin(X) & cos(X) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix} \right]
*
    \left[ \begin{matrix}
    cos(Y) & 0 & sin(Y) & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    -sin(Y) & 0 & cos(Y) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix} \right]
*
    \left[ \begin{matrix}
    cos(Z) & -sin(Z) & 0 & 0 \\
    sin(Z) & cos(Z) & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix} \right]
$$

While the other uses the additive inverse of the sinus :
$$
    \left[ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & cos(X) & sin(X) & 0 \\
    0 & -sin(X) & cos(X) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix} \right]
*
    \left[ \begin{matrix}
    cos(Y) & 0 & -sin(Y) & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    sin(Y) & 0 & cos(Y) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix} \right]
*
    \left[ \begin{matrix}
    cos(Z) & sin(Z) & 0 & 0 \\
    -sin(Z) & cos(Z) & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix} \right]
$$

---

EDIT:
To clear things up, this is the environnement I'm willing to work with :
[Unity Coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xnGu.jpg)

Comment: This comes down to a convention about orientations (whether $X$ corresponds to a rotation by $X$ radians "clockwise" or "counterclockwise"); I don't know what conventions are relevant here.

Comment: If the X axis is coming toward me, a X radian rotation is done Clockwise.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Unity uses a left-handed coordinate system. It has given me some headaches.

Comment: I attached a picture to show how this coordinate system works exactly.

Comment: The columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors. Figure out where you want them to end up and you won’t have to memorize formulas.